# Is it possible to set mod_expires directives dependent on REMOTE_ADDR?

Tags: apache-httpd, caching

Basically I have a bunch of `mod_expires` directives in my `httpd.conf` like so:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hour"
```

I realize that ultimately, the user's browser determines how long to hold onto something but the above suggestion is too long for the local users (`192.168.0.0/16`) but not long enough for internet visitors.

Is it possible to have one set of cache control suggestions for local address and another for the rest of the world (sort of if/else-style)? If so, how would I do that?

**EDIT:**

This won't help me and I don't have a 2.4 install available to test with right now but if anybody wants to take a crack at posting a solution [using 2.4's If/ElseIf/Else directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) I'll accept that as an answer and award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic setup that worked for me. If a request is made from the local network I get an expiration of 1 day, if done remotely it is 1 hour

```
ExpiresActive On
<If "-R '192.168.0.0/16'">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</If>
<Else>
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
</Else>
```